# $(...).jtable is not a function in Jquery 1.9.0 PlugIn

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

We are facing an issue with jTable with 1.9.0 plugIn. During debugging process it is been identified that jquery 1.9.0 is calling code.jquery.com/jquery 1.4.2. For more information included image.

We have tried by changing the sequence of jquery references in master page(layout.cshtml). But no result.

Strange issue: We have tried the same in various machines , many of them loading data properly and jquery 1.9.0 getting called , but we are facing this issue in few client machines. What would be the problem ?do we need to change any things from browser level? we have installed all latest version of browsers.

Thanks
Mohan Kadiyala

Answer (score -1):

YOu need to clear the cache of the browser in the machine.

you can also force the browser to reload the newest version of your page

### HTML

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

### [css](http://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/) / js

exemple :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1.1">
```

note the extra `?v=1.1` changing the value after '?v=' will force the broswer to load the new css/js.

### PHP

```
header("Content-type: text/html"); 
header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2000 12:00:00 GMT");  
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);  
header("Pragma: no-cache")
```

Here is are some posts concerning this :

1. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)
2. [link2](http://webdesign.about.com/od/caching/qt/control-the-browser-cache-with-expires-meta-tag.htm)
3. [link3](http://www.impressivewebs.com/force-browser-newest-stylesheet/)